# adding markers to google maps using information from sql databases

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a set of coordinates in a database that I want to be used to add markers on a google map

I created the following code

```
var map;
function initialize() 
  {
    var latloncenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51,-1.4469157);
    var myOptions = 
    {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latloncenter,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  }; 

  <? while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){?>

      var lon = "<?php echo($row['Longitude']); ?>"; 
      var lat = "<?php echo($row['Latitude']); ?>"; 


     //alert_test(lat,lon);
     setmarker(lat,lon);

<? } ?>



function setmarker(lat,lon)
{

var latlongMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    (
        {
            position: latlongMarker, 
            map: map,
            title:"Hello World!"
        }
    ); 

}

function alert_test(lat,lon)
{
    alert(lat +" "+ lon);
}
```

```
<body onload="initialize()"><div id="map_canvas"></div></body>
```

it's loading the map, and I know the query from the database is working correctly, However I think I am doing something wrong in the setmarker() method.... anyone knows how to make it work?

Comment: I'm confused. Why is $document ready inside the loop?

Comment: ah it's because i originally put it inside the <body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your PHP-setmarker loop inside `initialize()`. Please try it.

I don't know all the intricacies of JavaScript but I think it's a good idea to write `var` only once in `var lat, var lon` (it gets repeated in the PHP loop). Well, the JS interpreters probably don't care either way.

Comment: thanks man it worked , just curious why it had to be inside initialize ?